# Is it possible to get a solution for all inequality constraint values in Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, information-theory

I am reading a paper on the [Information Bottleneck Method](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/labs/learning/Papers/allerton.pdf).
In this paper authors give a short review of rate distortion theory.
In rate distortion theory we are interested in the rate distortion function $R(D)$, which is defined as
$$R(D) = \min_{p(\tilde x | x)} I(X, \tilde{X}) \qquad\text{such that}\quad \mathbb{E}_{p(x,\tilde x)}[d(x, \tilde x)] \leq D$$
where:

- $X$ is our source random variable. It is discrete and finite.
- $\tilde X$ is quantization of $X$ (this quantization is stochastic, i.e. we have a stochastic mapping $p(\tilde x | x)$)
- $d(x, \tilde x)$ is our distortion function, which measures the quality of quantization (in practice, it can be something like MSE error or Hamming distance)
- $\beta$ is the Lagrange multiplier

Authors say, that we do it by minimizing a Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{F}(p(\tilde x | x)) = I(X, \tilde{X}) + \beta \mathbb{E}_{p(x,\tilde x)}[d(x, \tilde x)]$$

There are two moments that I do not understand:

- Why second term in Lagrangian does not contain $D$? Wikipedia says, that inequality constraints "$g(x) \leq C$" should give second term of the kind "$\beta(g(x) - C)$", not "$\beta g(x)$". We somehow imply that $C = 0$ here?
- Why do authors say, that we find a whole function $R(D)$? It looks like we are finding just a single value of this function, evaluated at the point $D$, not the whole form of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite common in this kind of max/minimization problems.

In general, supose you want to find an extremum of $f(x)$ subject to $g(x)\le D$. The method of Lagrange multiplier does not adapt to this constraint. But, if if you have reasons to assume (we often have) that the constraint $g(x)\le D$ is "relevant / pessimistic", that is, that we wish $D$ to be bigger to get better extrema of $f(x)$, this implies that the extremum of $f(x)$ subject to $g(x)\le D$ will occur in the limit of the region, i.e., where $g(x)=D$ or $g(x)-D=0$. Then, we are justified in replacing the inequality by an equality.

Then, Lagrange multiplier tells us to find the extremum of the Lagrangian

$$J_1(x) = f(x) + \beta (g(x)-D) \tag1$$
together with  $g(x)-D=0$. But, because $D$ is constant, this is equivalent to find the extremum of the alternative Lagrangian

$$ J_2(x) =f(x) + \beta' g(x) \tag2$$

But to find the extremum  of $(2)$ is not the same as assuming $D=0$, because the additional equation $g(x)-D=0$ remains as is. Different values of $D$ will give different multipliers ($\beta \ne \beta'$) and hence different extrema.

Namely, if the extrema corresponds to a critical point, both $(1)$ and $(2)$ will lead to the same system of equations:

\begin{cases}
f'(x)+ \beta g'(x)&=0\\
g(x) -D &= 0 \tag3
\end{cases}

The solution, of course, depends on $D$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes things much more clear. So just to be sure: the solution to this optimization procedure does not give us the whole $R(D)$ function, but just its evaluation at a particular choice of $D$, right?

Comment: The solution of $(3)$ gives an extremum of $f$ (let's call it $f_0$) that depends on the value of $D$, hence it's a function of it: $f_0(D)$.  To get "the whole $R(D)$ function" and to get "the evaluation of $R$ a each value of $D$" are the same thing to me.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, in equation $(2)$ do we assume that $\beta'$ is fixed (i.e. $\beta' = 3$) before starting the optimization procedure? Because otherwise, if our $J_2(x)$ depends on $\beta'$ and we optimize for it too, then it is the same thing as assuming $D = 0$, isn't it?

Comment: No. $\beta$ is indeterminated. You should regard $(3)$ as a system of two equations with two unknowns: $x$ and $\beta$.

Comment: BTW, my other comment above is wrong , it should read "The solution of (3) gives the value of $x$ which attain the extremum (let's call it $x_0$); that depends on the value of $D$, hence it's a function of it: $x_0(D)$.

Comment: Thanks! As far as I understand now, we write $J(x) = f(x) + \beta g(x)$ instead of $J(x) = f(x) + \beta (g(x) - D)$ just for notational brevity. Is it true? Because otherwise I do not see any reasons of doing such things. BTW, why did you omit the dependence of Lagrangian on $\beta$ (i.e. writing $J_1(x)$ instead of $J_1(x, \beta)$)? For notational convenience or there is something behind this?